# hibernate query cant get the right result after database records changed by other application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching

I am a newbie to hibernate, got a problem really bothering me.

I have a mysql table named `codes`

```
+------+--------+------+
|id    | status | code |
+------+--------+------+
| 1    |  2     | 45234|
+------+--------+------+
| 2    |  1     | 54345|
+------+--------+------+
```

I have got a hibernate session from this singleton:

```
public class HBSession {
private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = ourSessionFactory.openSession();

    /** Here I have already tried 
    *    session.flush();
    *         or
    //   session.clear();
    **/

    return session;
  }

}
```

and I use this to fetch the result:

```
Session = HBSession.getSession();
String HQL = "From CodesEntity C WHERE C.status = 1";
Query query = session.createQuery(HQL);
List<CodesEntity> l = query.list();
session.close();
```

Everything works fine, if I use the same application to operating the mysql database.
but when database records has been updated by other application, like mysql-cli-client, I can't get the right result. Only get the old data.

I assume this may have some relation to hibernate's Caching mechanism. but I can't find the 
right way to make things work :-(

Comment: other applications means they have there own session factory..??

Comment: Probably data may have not been committed to database.

Comment: yes, I think so. In fact I just use the mysql-client such as `update codes set status = 2 where id = 2`

Comment: @DarshanLila I am  sure data has been committed, because I can see records changed using  mysql-client.

Comment: Based on info available I suggest you to debug your code and try various examinations. See if you can find something that might be causing the problem.

Comment: @DarshanLila I use the above code in a glassfish server, if I restart the server I got the right result.

Comment: Can you tell me when are you executing HQl queries? And also make sure you open and close a fresh session for every transaction.

Comment: @DarshanLila I make the code in a glassfish server and run it, then do the first query, got some data, then manually update a record's status by using the mysql-client, then I using the http server do a the same query, I expect the result to be different from the first query, because records has been changed. But I still got the same result. And YES, I carefully make sure that I committed the transaction and close the session after using it.

Comment: Try refreshing or flushing the session before you execute HQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by adding transaction with query. that is

```
Session session = HBSession.getSession();
String HQL = "FROM CodesEntity C where C.status = 1";
Transcation tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = Session.createQuery(HQL);
List<CodesEntity> l = query.list();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

And now I can get the data synced with the mysql database;

But if there is better way to make this work, let me know.

Comment: oh dear. Based on your original question, I had an impression that TX was already in place and working fine. Glad that fixed your problem.

Comment: My fault, as a newbie for hibernate, I haven't got a clear understanding of it's mechanism. I was convinced that transaction only needed when data modified(insert and update). never have a thought that query should use it to keep synced with the under-layout database too. Anyway, thanks for your patient :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes its true. This happens because Hibernate session factory caches stuff like queries and resultset ids and also entities. try the `evict, refresh, cacheMode` methods on Session to see what works in your case.

Comment: I have just tried adding  `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);` in the `public static Session getSession()` method, didn't get any luck :-(

Comment: try refresh method also. It is supposed to pull back all stuff from the underlying DB again.

Comment: `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)` didn't work either.

Comment: did u try the same things with the query also?

Comment: don't get what u means by try the same things.

Comment: You can use cacheMode combinations on Query object also. Did you tr that?

Comment: read this post http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/02/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works/ it will help in providing pointers to your case.

Comment: is there a way that I can just disable second level cache through hibernate.xml? like `<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>` and `<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>` ? I found it does't work. For the record, I have already tried using `CacheMode.IGNORE` and `CacheMode.REFRESH` in my query parase, but things still seem to be the same, this problem now almost drive me crazy. T-T